# facebook comments box in page source but not visible on site

Tags: facebook, drupal

I have a drupal site and I've set up a facebook apps for my site and installed the module https://drupal.org/project/facebook_comments. 
I've enabled the block but the facebook comments box is just not showing on my site. It appears in the page source but you can't see it on the screen. 
Randomly it does appear but maybe 3/4 times today and I've reloaded the page at least 50!
It is meant to show on http://jspca.org.il/en/success-stories/leo-dog-who-came-home if anyone know why it isn't showing up please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drupal module easy social https://drupal.org/project/easy_social was blocking facebook comments and causing the errors to show in the console. I was using 7x1 and so  updated to the latest easy social version 7x2.10 and the comments are showing fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the error console gives this:
[image: console log]

Looking at the source, you have 2 divs with the id fb-root - this is probably what's causing the error, get rid of one and see what happens.

Comment: thanks for the tip to check the console, I forgot about that.